# POSTGRESQL Self Join Create New Column With Particular Condition

Tags: postgresql, join, self-join

```sql
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "parrent_account" INTEGER,
  "merchant_type" VARCHAR(8),
  "name" VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO accounts
  ("id", "parrent_account", "merchant_type", "name")
VALUES
  (1, 14056, 'outlet', 'RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ NIPAH MAL'),
  (2, 14056, 'outlet', 'RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ SUNTER MALL'),
  (3, 14056, 'outlet', 'RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ BAYWALK PLUIT'),
  (3499, NULL, 'MERCHANT', 'Kopi Kotak'),
  (3500, 3499, 'OUTLET', 'Kopi Kotak Tebet'),
  (14052, NULL, 'GROUP', 'Champ Group'),
  (14056, 14052, 'MERCHANT', 'RAA CHA');
```

If parrent_account is null, an account doesn't have a merchant/group.

If merchant_type is outlet with parrent_account, the id (inside parrent_account) will refer to a merchant.

If merchant_type is merchant with parrent_account, the id (inside parrent_account) will refer to a group.

Expected result:

| id | parrent_account | merchant_type | name | MERCHANT | GROUP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ NIPAH MAL | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 2 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ SUNTER MALL | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 3 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ BAYWALK PLUIT | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 3499 | NULL | MERCHANT | Kopi Kotak |  |  |
| 3500 | 3499 | OUTLET | Kopi Kotak Tebet | Kopi Kotak |  |
| 14052 | NULL | GROUP | Champ Group |  |  |
| 14056 | 14052 | MERCHANT | RAA CHA |  | Champ Group |

**Query #1 and result:**

(CHAMP GROUP in row 6 should be in the group field.)

```
select v_outlet.*
, v_merchant.name as merchant
, v_group.name as group
from accounts v_outlet
left join accounts v_merchant on v_outlet.parrent_account = v_merchant.id
left join accounts v_group on v_merchant.parrent_account = v_group.id;
```

| id | parrent_account | merchant_type | name | merchant | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ BAYWALK PLUIT | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 2 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ SUNTER MALL | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 1 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ NIPAH MAL | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 3500 | 3499 | OUTLET | Kopi Kotak Tebet | Kopi Kotak |  |
| 14052 |  | GROUP | Champ Group |  |  |
| 14056 | 14052 | MERCHANT | RAA CHA | Champ Group |  |
| 3499 |  | MERCHANT | Kopi Kotak |  |  |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9BStxo95osxAd6cwwefNtS/0)

**Query #2 and result:**

(In row 6 RAA CHA has a group, but the result is null.)

```
select v_outlet.*
, v_merchant.name as merchant
, v_group.name as group
from accounts v_outlet
left join accounts v_merchant on v_outlet.merchant_type in ('outlet', 'OUTLET') and v_outlet.parrent_account = v_merchant.id
left join accounts v_group on v_merchant.merchant_type in ('merchant', 'MERCHANT') and v_merchant.parrent_account = v_group.id;
```

| id | parrent_account | merchant_type | name | merchant | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ BAYWALK PLUIT | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 2 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ SUNTER MALL | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 1 | 14056 | outlet | RAA CHA SUKI & BBQ NIPAH MAL | RAA CHA | Champ Group |
| 3500 | 3499 | OUTLET | Kopi Kotak Tebet | Kopi Kotak |  |
| 14052 |  | GROUP | Champ Group |  |  |
| 14056 | 14052 | MERCHANT | RAA CHA |  |  |
| 3499 |  | MERCHANT | Kopi Kotak |  |  |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r6nkUDuWMaTLT1yTSPRxTu/0)

Comment: Debug posts require a MRE--[mre]. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.[ask] [Help] Either ask about 1 coding error while giving a MRE or ask about 1 place you are stuck while giving relevant working parts & no code with errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra join

1. if the account is an outlet, get its merchant
2. using merchants from #1, get their group
3. if the account is a merchant, get its group

```sql
select v_outlet.*
, v_merchant.name as merchant
, coalesce(v_group.name, v_group2.name) as group
from accounts v_outlet
left join accounts v_merchant on v_outlet.merchant_type in ('outlet', 'OUTLET') and v_outlet.parrent_account = v_merchant.id
left join accounts v_group on v_merchant.merchant_type in ('merchant', 'MERCHANT') and v_merchant.parrent_account = v_group.id
left join accounts v_group2 on v_outlet.merchant_type in ('merchant', 'MERCHANT') and v_outlet.parrent_account = v_group2.id
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r6nkUDuWMaTLT1yTSPRxTu/1)

Comment: @Yogyakartas The way to "thank" for the best answer is to click on the acceptance check mark. [help]

Answer (score 0):

The results of your first attempt as per the DBFiddle responses are

[image]

which differ from the results you intended to obtain in having `null` shown instead of empty Strings where there is no value. You can explicitly list your fields and use `COALESCE(<yourfield>, '')` to convert those nulls into empty strings:

```
select  v_outlet.id
, v_outlet.parrent_account
, v_outlet.merchant_type
, COALESCE(v_outlet.name, '') AS name
, CASE WHEN v_group.name IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(v_merchant.name, '') ELSE '' END AS merchant
, CASE WHEN v_group.name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(v_merchant.name, '') ELSE '' END AS group
from accounts v_outlet
left join accounts v_merchant on v_outlet.parrent_account = v_merchant.id
left join accounts v_group on v_merchant.parrent_account = v_group.id
order by v_outlet.id
```

See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9BStxo95osxAd6cwwefNtS/2

[image]